# Building Asp.net Dynamic Data Web Application Over LightSwitch OData Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

Im having an OData Service exposed from LightSwitch im trying to register the context of asp.net data dynamic web application over the Service

```
northwindData context = new LSService.northwindData(new Uri("http://localhost/northwindlob/northwinddata.svc/"));

DefaultModel.RegisterContext(//Not sure what i should type here!);
```

any idea?

Comment: not really, i wonder if its even possible...